# better query plan to improve speed

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance

I want to improve query plan so It gives me results in milliseconds. right now, this query gives result in 1.9 seconds

Here is the query

```
explain (analyze on, buffers on, verbose on) select "tbl_users"."id",
coalesce(SUM(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value), 0)::INTEGER as total_distance, 
coalesce(SUM(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value), 0)::INTEGER as total_time, 
(select count(*) from "vw_routes_stop_address" where "tbl_users"."id" = "vw_routes_stop_address"."i_user_id" and "i_route_id" ='30581' and "e_row_status" ='Active' and "e_stop_address_type" ='Stop') as "route_stops_count" 
from "tbl_users" 
inner join "tbl_team_members" on "tbl_team_members"."i_user_id" = "tbl_users"."id" 
left join "tbl_routes" on tbl_users.id::varchar = any(string_to_array(tbl_routes.v_selected_driver_ids, ',')) 
left join "tbl_routes_stop_address" on "tbl_routes_stop_address"."i_route_id" = "tbl_routes"."id" 
where "tbl_routes"."id" ='30581' and "tbl_users"."e_row_status" ='Active' and 
("tbl_routes_stop_address"."id" is null or ("tbl_routes_stop_address"."id" is not null and "e_stop_address_type" ='Stop' and "tbl_routes_stop_address"."e_row_status" ='Active')) 
group by "tbl_users"."id", "tbl_team_members"."id", "tbl_routes"."v_name", "tbl_routes"."e_route_status", "v_pin_color", "e_units" limit 100 offset 0;
```

Here is query plan

```
Limit  (cost=1149.84..3263.09 rows=100 width=71) (actual time=1246.036..1246.067 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: tbl_users.id, ((COALESCE(sum(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value), '0'::double precision))::integer), ((COALESCE(sum(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value), '0'::bigint))::integer), ((SubPlan 1)), tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_team_members.v_pin_color, tbl_routes.e_units
   Buffers: shared hit=21263 read=1, temp read=834 written=839
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1149.84..7024.67 rows=278 width=71) (actual time=1246.032..1246.060 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: tbl_users.id, (COALESCE(sum(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value), '0'::double precision))::integer, (COALESCE(sum(tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value), '0'::bigint))::integer, (SubPlan 1), tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_team_members.v_pin_color, tbl_routes.e_units
         Group Key: tbl_users.id, tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units
         Buffers: shared hit=21263 read=1, temp read=834 written=839
         ->  Sort  (cost=1149.84..1150.53 rows=278 width=67) (actual time=726.223..726.269 rows=38 loops=1)
               Output: tbl_users.id, tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value, tbl_team_members.v_pin_color
               Sort Key: tbl_users.id, tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
               Buffers: shared hit=17851
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.29..1138.55 rows=278 width=67) (actual time=19.878..726.080 rows=38 loops=1)
                     Output: tbl_users.id, tbl_team_members.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value, tbl_team_members.v_pin_color
                     Buffers: shared hit=17845
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.00..1031.78 rows=279 width=52) (actual time=19.839..725.519 rows=38 loops=1)
                           Output: tbl_users.id, tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value
                           Join Filter: (((tbl_users.id)::character varying)::text = ANY (string_to_array(tbl_routes.v_selected_driver_ids, ','::text)))
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 354616
                           Buffers: shared hit=17731
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.00..164.64 rows=1 width=49) (actual time=0.100..0.383 rows=38 loops=1)
                                 Output: tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units, tbl_routes.v_selected_driver_ids, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value
                                 Join Filter: (tbl_routes_stop_address.i_route_id = tbl_routes.id)
                                 Filter: ((tbl_routes_stop_address.id IS NULL) OR ((tbl_routes_stop_address.id IS NOT NULL) AND ((tbl_routes_stop_address.e_stop_address_type)::text = 'Stop'::text) AND ((tbl_routes_stop_address.e_row_status)::text = 'Active'::text)))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                 Buffers: shared hit=23
                                 ->  Index Scan using tbl_routes_pkey1 on public.tbl_routes  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.035..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
                                       Output: tbl_routes.v_name, tbl_routes.e_route_status, tbl_routes.e_units, tbl_routes.v_selected_driver_ids, tbl_routes.id
                                       Index Cond: (tbl_routes.id = '30581'::bigint)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=3
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.tbl_routes_stop_address  (cost=4.72..155.66 rows=39 width=35) (actual time=0.057..0.233 rows=40 loops=1)
                                       Output: tbl_routes_stop_address.d_distance_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.d_duration_value, tbl_routes_stop_address.i_route_id, tbl_routes_stop_address.id, tbl_routes_stop_address.e_stop_address_type, tbl_routes_stop_address.e_row_status
                                       Recheck Cond: (tbl_routes_stop_address.i_route_id = '30581'::bigint)
                                       Heap Blocks: exact=14
                                       Buffers: shared hit=20
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_service_time  (cost=0.00..4.71 rows=39 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=40 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: (tbl_routes_stop_address.i_route_id = '30581'::bigint)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=6
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.tbl_users  (cost=0.00..588.52 rows=9287 width=8) (actual time=0.003..9.254 rows=9333 loops=38)
                                 Output: tbl_users.id
                                 Filter: ((tbl_users.e_row_status)::text = 'Active'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 535
Buffers: shared hit=17708
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_i_user_id_tbl_team_members on public.tbl_team_members  (cost=0.29..0.37 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=38)
                           Output: tbl_team_members.id, tbl_team_members.i_owner_id, tbl_team_members.i_user_id, tbl_team_members.e_user_role, tbl_team_members.v_pin_color, tbl_team_members.e_invite_status, tbl_team_members.e_licence_status, tbl_team_members.i_device_id, tbl_team_members.e_row_status, tbl_team_members.v_api_version, tbl_team_members.created_at, tbl_team_members.updated_at
                           Index Cond: (tbl_team_members.i_user_id = tbl_users.id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=114
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=21.09..21.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=519.724..519.732 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: count(*)
                 Buffers: shared hit=3412 read=1, temp read=834 written=839
                 ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=8.46..21.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=509.836..519.695 rows=38 loops=1)
                       Inner Unique: true
                       Hash Cond: (ct.i_route_stop_id = tbl_routes_stop_address_1.id)
                       Buffers: shared hit=3412 read=1, temp read=834 written=839
                       ->  Function Scan on public.crosstab ct  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=438.232..477.934 rows=60564 loops=1)
                             Output: ct.i_route_stop_id, ct.custom1, ct.custom2, ct.custom3, ct.custom4, ct.custom5
                             Function Call: crosstab('SELECT i_route_stop_id, v_custom_field, v_custom_field_value
                 FROM   tbl_routes_stop_custom_fields
                 ORDER  BY 1,2 ASC'::text, 'VALUES (''custom1''::varchar),(''custom2''::varchar),(''custom3''::varchar),(''custom4''::varchar),(''custom5''::varchar)'::text)
                             Buffers: shared hit=3375, temp read=834 written=839
                       ->  Hash  (cost=8.45..8.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.214..0.217 rows=38 loops=1)
                             Output: tbl_routes_stop_address_1.id
                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                             Buffers: shared hit=34 read=1
                             ->  Index Scan using idx_i_user_id_i_route_id_l_address_tbl_routes_stop_address on public.tbl_routes_stop_address tbl_routes_stop_address_1  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.100..0.166 rows=38 loops=1)
                                   Output: tbl_routes_stop_address_1.id
                                   Index Cond: ((tbl_routes_stop_address_1.i_user_id = tbl_users.id) AND (tbl_routes_stop_address_1.i_route_id = 30581))
                                   Filter: (((tbl_routes_stop_address_1.e_row_status)::text = 'Active'::text) AND ((tbl_routes_stop_address_1.e_stop_address_type)::text = 'Stop'::text))
                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                   Buffers: shared hit=34 read=1
 Planning Time: 2.666 ms
 Execution Time: 1247.399 ms
(73 rows)
```

Comment: There are three points where your time is lost: The `crosstab` invocation, the join with the `string_to_array` call, and the frequent scan on `tbl_users` caused by the bad estimate of the join between `tbl_routes` and `tbl_routes_stop_address`, which has a complicated join condition. Try improving any of these, and performance will get better.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather hard to give specific advice as you don't describe at all what the query does and much of the guts of the end query seem to be hidden in views we can't see.  The formatting doesn't really help either.

You can try to get rid of that repetitive table scan of tbl_users by adding an index:

```
on tbl_users (e_row_status, id)
```

Although given the bad estimate I don't know if it will choose to use it.

The crosstab is also an obvious time sink, but it is a black box.  You could pull the text of the first argument of that out of the function call and EXPLAIN that as a standalone query, and then try to optimize that.  But it would probably be better to try to rewrite the query so as not to use crosstab at all.

Turning on track_io_timing will also help by making the plans you get more informative.